# Callbacks as object properties

Tags: javascript

I would like to get a similar functionality to this:

```
function foo(before, after){

    before();

    setTimeout(function(){
         after();
    },100)
}

foo(function(){
    console.log('before');
}, function(){
    console.log('after');
});
```

When returning an object instead of using callbacks (psuedo code):

```
var foo = function() {

     before();         

     setTimeout(function(){
         after();
     },100)

     return {
         before: before,
         after: after
     }
};

foo().before(function(){
    console.log('before');
});

foo().after(function(){
    console.log('after');
});
```

Or perhaps even

```
foo().before(function(){
    console.log('before');
}).after(function(){
    console.log('after');
});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your function can return an object with `before` and `after` methods that keep track of which callbacks has been set, and when both are set it can call them:

```
function foo() {

    var beforeFunc = null, afterFunc = null;

    function activate() {
        beforeFunc();
        window.setTimeout(afterFunc, 100);
    }

    var obj = {
        before: function(f) {
            beforeFunc = f;
            if (afterFunc != null) activate();
            return obj;
        },
        after: function(f) {
            afterFunc = f;
            if (beforeFunc != null) activate();
            return obj;
        }
    };

    return obj;

}

// As both callbacks need to be set, the order is not important
foo().after(function(){
    console.log('After');
}).before(function(){
    console.log('Before');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4HypB/

Answer (score 2):

It's *almost* possible.

The problem with your proposed usage example, though, is that it involves `foo()` being called before `before` or `after` callbacks are specified. Meanwhile, in your example implementation, these callbacks are executed within `foo`. So *that* isn't achievable: you can't retroactively change what happened in a method after that method has already run.

If what you really want is for the callbacks supplied via `foo` to be executed *nearly* right away—i.e, if pure synchronous execution isn't mandatory—you can get what you're after with a simple `setTimeout` call:

```
function foo() {
  var callbacks = {
    before: function() {},
    after: function() {}
  };

  setTimeout(function() {
    callbacks.before();
    setTimeout(callbacks.after, 100);
  }, 0);

  return {
    before: function(callback) {
      callbacks.before = callback;
      return this;
    },

    after: function(callback) {
      callbacks.after = callback;
    }
  };
}
```

Here, `foo()` will return an object that exposes methods to modify the `callbacks` object closed over within the method body of `foo`. These methods will then be used on the next tick of the event loop, *after* `foo()` has executed.

I've created [an example at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AcUXeXA/1/edit) if you're interested in seeing this code in action.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(){};
foo.prototype.before = function(f){ this._before = f };
foo.prototype.after  = function(f){ this._after  = f };
foo.prototype.go = function(){
  this._before();
  setTimeout(this._after,100);
}

var f = new foo;
f.before(function(){ … });
f.after(function(){ … });
f.go();
```

But then again, you might as well make this simpler:

```
function foo(){};
foo.prototype.go = function(){
  this.before();
  setTimeout(this.after,100);
}

var f = new foo;
f.before = function(){ … };
f.after  = function(){ … };
f.go();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation:

```
var createFooBuilder = function () {
    var before = function() {};
    var after = function() {};

    var func = function () {
        before();
        setTimeout(function () {
            after();
        }, 100)
    };

    func.before = function(value) {
        before = value;
        return func;
    }
    func.after = function(value) {
        after = value;
        return func;
    }

    return func;
};

var foo = createFooBuilder();

foo.before(function () {
    console.log('before');
}).after(function () {
    console.log('after');
});

foo();
```

I'd certainly recommend trying to make [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)s work for you, then you can have lists of after functions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using that actually. But I'm trying to extend it so that I get a "before"-function as well. Because AFAIK, there is none.

Comment: Yes, it is tricky to add before functionality. The beauty of deferreds is that you can pass them around and add callbacks even once the deferred is resolved, adding callbacks which should run before the deferred is resolved after it has resolved is tricky... what does your usecase look like?

Comment: I'm just playing around a bit but http://jsfiddle.net/zfqJ8/53/ Instead of just exposing the promise, my idea was to expose parts of the promise + some custom methods, like "before" for instance.

Comment: I suppose `progress` is a little like before, in that it gets called before the deferred is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Phrogz' answer is good but FWIW you can also do this without prototypes:

```
function foo() {
  ret = function () { return ret.call(); };
  ret.call = function () {
    this._before();
    setTimeout(this._after,100);
  };
  ret.before = function (x) { this._before = x; return this; };
  ret.after = function (x) { this._after = x; return this; };
  return ret;
};

test = foo().before(function(){
  console.log('before');
}).after(function(){
  console.log('after');
});
```

Calling:

```
test();
```

does what you would expect.